# Extract City Name in Talend

Tags: extract, talend

I have here a sample data where I want to put the city on a separate column. The city can be defined after the comma sign. How can I do this with talend. What component should I use?

Here's the sample data. On the left side is my input and the right should be the right output.

[image]

Comment: is city always come at the last potions of address filed? If yes then you can use this row1.Address.split(",") and take last index of array to get last word.

Comment: yes. it's always after the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split function in tMap. use below code in city column just change dwetl address field with your actual column name.

```
!Relational.ISNULL(row7.dwetl_Address)?row7.dwetl_Address.split(",")[1]:"default City"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the logic for extracting city either in a tMap (create variable in tmap to do parsing) or you can use a tJavaRow component to do this.

Just search for indexOf and substring methods to do your parsing.

For example in tJavaRow you can use

```
output_row.city = input_row.addressfield.substring(input_row.addressfield.indexOf(",")+1).trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can create your own routine and make it more generic by using StringTokenizer(you may use split but I prefer the later) and then you can also pass the string separator to the routine as an argument and and return the position as you want.

This will make the routine to be reusable and you can also use it later. And the routine can be called through tMap.